# Joomla 2.5 component upgrade while keeping file unchanged

Tags: joomla, components, upgrade

I have wrote a custom joomla 2.5 component and I its deployed on various sites with each having its own style sheet changed on server.. is there a way I can keep upgrading the component (add new features etc) but make sure that a specific css file is not not changed? i.e. remains the same as updated on each website?

Comment: Where are you storing the style sheet? Do you just want to not touch it or do you want to change it during update?

Comment: If you don't want to change it you can just skipp it in the extension package. When upgrading, old files **should** remain on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you have the xml file correctly set to method upgrade     `<extension type="component" version="1.6.0" method="upgrade">` just skip the     `<folder>css</folder>` on your upgrade package.

```
    <files folder="site">
        <filename>index.html</filename>
        <filename>keywords_editor.php</filename>
        <filename>controller.php</filename>
        <filename>router.php</filename>
        <folder>views</folder>
        <folder>css</folder> // This should not be included in your case
        <folder>models</folder>
        <folder>controllers</folder>
        <folder>helpers</folder>
    </files>
```

As Valentin mentions, the old files will remain on server if you're doing an upgrade to the component and not a fresh install.

Comment: This won't work.. I tried it and it deleted the previous folder.. in this case css.

Comment: I mean, `<folder>css</folder>` empty folder. It must stay in the xml declaration.